# Screen goes black when changing activity in Android app

Tags: android

I am trying to make a simple android app. The goal is to have 2 activities. In the first (Main activity) there is some information on the purpose of the app, and a startbutton. Clicking the startbutton should change activity to "CalculatingActivity". In this activity there are a textview displaying a number. This number is the sum of two ints between 1 and 10. There are 4 butttons each showing to ints added together. One of them is the right alternative. There is a mechanism counting wrongs, and when 10 right answers have been given, the program ends. 
However I can´t test the code yet because when I click the startbutton in MainActivity the screen goes black. I have tried to find out why. If I cut out the code from the last while-loop, the second activity screen shows, som there must be something wrong with  the code here, but I cannot find out what it is...

Here is the code for the mainActivity:
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button startButton;
    private TextView txtView1;
    private TextView txtView2;
    private TextView txtView3;
    private TextView txtView4;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartButton);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CalculatingActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And here is the code for the second activity (CalculatingActivity):

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.Random;

public class CalculatingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int a,b; // Numbers
    private int a1,b1,a2,b2,a3,b3;// False numbers
    private int c; //= a + b
    private Button button1;
    private Button button2;
    private Button button3;
    private Button button4;
    private Button backButton;
    private TextView sum;
    private TextView resultat;
    private int countWrong = 0;
    private boolean correctButton1 = false;
    private boolean correctButton2 = false;
    private boolean correctButton3 = false;
    private boolean correctButton4 = false;
    private boolean nextRound = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculating);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    final Random rndNumber = new Random();
    sum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    resultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    boolean play = false;


    for (final int[] countRight = {1}; countRight[0] <= 10; countRight[0]++) {
        a = rndNumber.nextInt(9) + 1;
        String strA = Integer.toString(a);       //Transfering int numbers to strings
        b = rndNumber.nextInt(9) + 1;
        String strB = Integer.toString(b);
        a1 = rndNumber.nextInt(9) + 1;
        String strA1 = Integer.toString(a1);
        b1 = rndNumber.nextInt(9) + 1;
        String strB1 = Integer.toString(b1);
        a2 = rndNumber.nextInt(9) + 1;
        String strA2 = Integer.toString(a2);
        b2 = rndNumber.nextInt(9) + 1;
        String strB2 = Integer.toString(b2);
        a3 = rndNumber.nextInt(9) + 1;
        String strA3 = Integer.toString(a3);
        b3 = rndNumber.nextInt(9) + 1;
        String strB3 = Integer.toString(b3);
        c = a + b;
        sum.setText(Integer.toString(c));    //Display sum in Textview (sum)!

        String buttonArray[] = {(strA + " + " + strB), (strA1 + " + " + strB1), (strA2 + " + " + strB2), (strA3 + " + " + strB3)}; //Plasserer regnestykkene i rekkefølge.

        int[] randomArray = {-1, -1, -1, -1};  //Genererating random Array
        int counter = 0;
        int randomArrNumber;
        while (counter <= 3) {
            boolean add = true;
            randomArrNumber = rndNumber.nextInt(4);
            if (randomArrNumber == randomArray[counter]) {
                add = false;
            }
            if (counter == 1 && randomArrNumber == randomArray[0]) {
                add = false;
            }
            if (counter == 2 && randomArrNumber == randomArray[0]) {
                add = false;
            }
            if (counter == 2 && randomArrNumber == randomArray[1]) {
                add = false;
            }
            if (counter == 3 && randomArrNumber == randomArray[0]) {
                add = false;
            }
            if (counter == 3 && randomArrNumber == randomArray[1]) {
                add = false;
            }
            if (counter == 3 && randomArrNumber == randomArray[2]) {
                add = false;
            }
            if (add == true) {
                randomArray[counter] = randomArrNumber;
                counter++;
            }

        }   //End while-loop Random Array generated


        //Displaying numbers on buttons, and linking right buttons
        button1.setText(buttonArray[randomArray[0]]);
        if (buttonArray[0].equals(buttonArray[randomArray[0]])) {
            correctButton1 = true;
        }
        button2.setText(buttonArray[randomArray[1]]);
        if (buttonArray[0].equals(buttonArray[randomArray[1]])) {
            correctButton2 = true;
        }
        button3.setText(buttonArray[randomArray[2]]);
        if (buttonArray[0].equals(buttonArray[randomArray[2]])) {
            correctButton3 = true;
        }
        button4.setText(buttonArray[randomArray[3]]);
        if (buttonArray[0].equals(buttonArray[randomArray[3]])) {
            correctButton4 = true;
        }

        //Program runs fine until here. When code under here is taken out second activity runs fine.
        //Generating listeners to all buttons:
        while (nextRound == false) {
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (correctButton1 == true) {
                        countRight[0]++;
                        nextRound = true;
                    } else {
                        countWrong++;
                    }
                }   //End onClick
            });// End button1 OnClick listener

            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (correctButton2 == true) {
                        countRight[0]++;
                        nextRound = true;
                    } else {
                        countWrong++;
                    }
                }   //End onClick
            });// End button2 OnClick listener

            button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (correctButton3 == true) {
                        countRight[0]++;
                        nextRound = true;
                    } else {
                        countWrong++;
                    }
                }   //End onClick
            });// End button3 OnClick listener

            button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (correctButton4 == true) {
                        countRight[0]++;
                        nextRound = true;
                    } else {
                        countWrong++;
                    }
                }   //End onClick(View v)
            });// End button4 OnClick listener
        }// End while(nextRound == false)


    }   //End for-countRight-loop

    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CalculatingActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }//End On click
    });//End backButton listener

}//End onCreate

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_calculating, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you've got an infinite loop here:

```
while (nextRound == false) {
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (correctButton1 == true) {
                    countRight[0]++;
                    nextRound = true;
                } else {
                    countWrong++;
                }
            }   //End onClick
        });// End button1 OnClick listener

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (correctButton2 == true) {
                    countRight[0]++;
                    nextRound = true;
                } else {
                    countWrong++;
                }
            }   //End onClick
        });// End button2 OnClick listener

        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (correctButton3 == true) {
                    countRight[0]++;
                    nextRound = true;
                } else {
                    countWrong++;
                }
            }   //End onClick
        });// End button3 OnClick listener

        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (correctButton4 == true) {
                    countRight[0]++;
                    nextRound = true;
                } else {
                    countWrong++;
                }
            }   //End onClick(View v)
        });// End button4 OnClick listener
    }// End while(nextRound == false)
```

You only need to set the listeners once.  Just get rid of the while loop and you can move forward.

Comment: Thank you! No more black screen. The next activity starts now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add intents and run `startActivity(intent);` in your onClick listeners

you do it in your backbutton onClick but not many of the other ones.

Comment: Aren´t the intents used for changing activity? The other onClickListeners are just used for checking if the user has pushed the right button, not for starting a new activity. Or have I misunderstood the using of onClickListeners?

Comment: Opps you are right! Where is the startbutton defined so that it launched the correct activity?

Comment: The startbutton is initialized and connected to the activity_Main XML file in the main activity: private Button startButton; startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartButton);